# Admin Ticket: [osticket] should be cleaned!

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

We need to clean-up [osticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osticket). I saw this while viewing a bad question, so I went to look at the excerpt:

> osTicket is a widely-used open source support ticket system. It seamlessly integrates inquiries created via email and web-based forms into a simple easy to use multi-user web interface.

This is a magnet for bad questions. Excerpt from questions:

> I am having an serious issue , mail is not delivering to admin & agents email id while creating a new ticket , else than that mail are getting delivered successfully on the customers email id who is creating the ticket.

Below is a whole "question":

> I have installed osTicket-v1.9.12 but there is no option for automatic sending notification mail to user who has created ticket when i have assigned ticket to Agent/support member.

We need to clean this tag, then we should see what to do about the rest. I have been notified that a burninate probably wouldn't be appropriate for this tag.

Comment: You should create an [osticket] for that